# Buttons sticking to the left TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Notepad-esque program in TKinter as practice. how would I make the save button and open button stick onto the left side?

```
root = tk.Tk()


btn_frame = tk.Frame(root)
btn_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

save_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Save')
save_btn.pack(side='left')
open_btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Open')
open_btn.pack(side='left')

txtbox = tk.Text(root, font=('Consolas', 12), height=200)
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, command=txtbox.yview)
txtbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

txtbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
scroll.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

**Note: btn_frame must use grid and not place or pack.**

None of the things I tried with sticky or anchor worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting `sticky="w"` (or `"ew"`) in `btn_frame.grid(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

To make the "Save" and "Open" buttons stick to the left side in a Tkinter GUI, you can use the pack() geometry manager. Here's a basic example of how you might structure your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "w") as file:
            file.write(text_widget.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            content = file.read()
            text_widget.delete("1.0", "end")
            text_widget.insert("1.0", content)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Notepad")

text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)  # Text widget takes remaining space

save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Save", command=save_file)
save_button.pack(side="left")

open_button = tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=open_file)
open_button.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

In this example, the pack(side="left") method for the "Save" and "Open" buttons will make them stick to the left side of the window. The Text widget is given the remaining space to expand and fill the window. The command parameter of the buttons is set to the corresponding functions save_file() and open_file() that you would define to handle saving and opening files.